# Problem with extracting method that has one difference inside

Tags: java, for-loop

This is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < Board.COLUMN_SIZE; i++) {
    boolean[] present = initializeBooleanArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < Board.COLUMN_SIZE; j++) {
        present[board.getArray()[i][j] - 1] = true;
    }
}
```

And similar part of code

```
for (int i = 0; i < Board.COLUMN_SIZE; i++) {
    boolean[] present = initializeBooleanArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < Board.COLUMN_SIZE; j++) {
        present[board.getArray()[j][i] - 1] = true;
    }
}
```

Difference

```
present[board.getArray()[i][j] - 1] = true;
```

```
present[board.getArray()[j][i] - 1] = true;
```

How can I extract this block of code to function? I tried to use functional inteface, but have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: Some reason you can't set every element to `true` **in** `initializeBooleanArray()`?

Comment: You can accept an `IntBinaryOperator lookup` and do `present[lookup.applyAsInt(i, j) - 1] = true;`. Then have one caller pass `(i, j) -> board.getArray()[i, j]` and the other `(i, j) -> board.getArray()[j, i]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `boolean` parameter to the extracted method to indicate whether to swap `i` and `j`.  Like this.

```
private void updateArray(Board board, boolean transpose) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Board.COLUMN_SIZE; i++) {
        boolean[] present = initializeBooleanArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < Board.COLUMN_SIZE; j++) {
            int index = transpose ? board.getArray()[j][i] : board.getArray()[i][j];
            present[index - 1] = true;
        }
    }
}
```